# Can Jeddict be installed on Netbeans 11?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, netbeans-11

I cannot install the jeddict plugin on Netbeans 11.

I installed Netbeans 11 on my Windows 10 laptop. I try to install the jeddict plugin and a window with broken dependencies comes up. It seems that the jeddict plugin is expected to be installed only on Netbeans 10.

No code related

No expected results expected out of programming. I am only expecting a reply whether jeddict could be installed on Netbeans 11 and if there is a provision for this...

Comment: I have your same question, I would just like to point out that we are talking about Jeddict + Netbeans 11 + Java 8, right?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

As noted on [the Jeddict download page](https://jeddict.github.io/page.html?l=p/download), Jeddict v5.3 of is compatible with NetBeans v11.1, and Jeddict v5.4.1 is compatible with NetBeans v11.2.  Both can be downloaded from that page.

The current version, as of this answer, is Jeddict v5.4.2, which is compatible with NetBeans v12.0.